# HTTP DELETE with WebApi - passing a URL to the controller from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api

My WebApi controller looks like this:

```
    [HttpDelete]
    [Route("api/eventMetadataByPath/{mediaPath}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage DeleteEventMetadataByPath(string mediaPath)
    {
          // do stuff
    }
```

And my JS looks like this:

```
  eventService.sendRequest("DELETE", "eventMetadataByPath/" + mediaPath);
```

With eventService doing the following:

```
  const options = { url: self.baseUrl + self.apiEndpoint + extension } // localhost/eventMedtadataByPath/google.com
  return $.ajax(options)
```

How can I get the URL encoded as a URI parameter clientside so that the api controller can receive it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming eventService is below.  jQuery is your game, your best bet is to read the [jQuery.ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) as it covers all of your HTTP Request Types.

So for DELETE, In your options object, you're going to add

```
var eventService = {
  sendRequest : function (parameterValueThatIsDelete, extension) {

  const options = { 
    url: self.baseUrl + self.apiEndpoint + extension,
    type : parameterValueThatIsDelete
  }
  }
}
```